# 時系列データで期間を限定する

Tags: python, python3

kaggleのWalmart Recruiting Store Sales Forecastingに挑戦しています。
https://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-store-sales-forecasting
pandasのデータフレームから2010年のみのデータを抽出したいのですが、
どのようなコードを書けばよいでしょうか？
Dateは以下のコードでDatetime型にしました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
train=pd.read_csv("train.csv")
```

## Date列全体をstrptime関数に入れることができないので、関数を用意して、apply関数で加工する

```
import datetime
def str2date(x):
   return datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

## 時間型に直した列データを、Date2に格納

```
train['Date2'] = train['Date'].apply(str2date)
train=train.drop(["Date"],axis=1)
```

## Date2の型を確認

```
type(train.loc[5,'Date2'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

これで良いかと思います。

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
print(df.loc[df['Date'].dt.year == 2010])
```

Comment: 大変シンプルなコードで勉強になりました。ありがとうございました！